How to record mp3 (variable bitrate) with AudioKit?
I want to use NodeRecorder to record mp3-vbr. My research shows that the latest NodeRecorder does not take a file: with format as stated in this issue.
As NodeRecorder only records raw audio, I think I need FormatConverter to do this job after the raw audio file is saved.
My question:

Is this the correct way to record to mp3?
I wanted to use variable bitrate, but there is no such setting in FormatConverter.Options, is FormatConverter limited to a constant bitrate?


My findings:

AudioKit does not export to MP3, probably because it is a proprietary format even though it is widely used
AudioKit does support MP3 import, that's why there is .mp3 enum in FormatConverter
There is no vbr support

